# Confusing documentation on C's stat() function

Tags: c, struct, stat

I'm trying to inspect a file using `stat()`. The documentation states that the fucntion will return a `struct` called `stat` with all relevant information. However, right below that it simply says

> On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

So is the zero returned along with the struct? Do they both get returned in an array, or something? I'm very new to C and I'm not even sure if a `struct` can be an array item.

Comment: "return" is a bit of artistic licence, it doesn't use the *return value* for this info, but an 'out' parameter

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a pointer to a struct of that type, and it will get filled.

Yes, the wording is a bit confusing, but it means the function *returns* 0 or -1, and 'returns' the data you want in your parameter. Check here: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:stat

Comment: Its not irritating at all..All the syscalls need to have an error handling method and `stat()` for that matter can use a lot of error handling like if the file is not present or no proper permission is given to for that user, `stat()` should report the error and the ERRNO will provide info for the error. That's the standard way of doing it. Just because OP is confused doesn't make it irritating

Comment: The 'irritating' point is that the same verb is used for the *returned* status and the *returned* structure, one is the return value of the function, the other gets filled inside the parameter. 'Irritating' was a bad choice of word by me, maybe confusing would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is either success or error and you pass the address of a `struct stat` as one of the arguments

Check for errors and if there are none (the return value is `0`) then assume that the passed `stuct stat` now has valid information: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: I understand. So can I simply say something like `good = stat(inputFile, &someStruct)`? I can then check to make sure `good != 0`? Or can I just check if the function working implicitly by looking at the contents of `someStruct`? I' guessing not, because the memory locations in the struct has data in it anyway?

Comment: `0` actually means success. Check that `good == 0` and if that is true then use the `struct stat` however you would like

Comment: Ah you're right. But is that overkill? Does a checker variable like this _need_ to be created, or can I tell if the function worked by looking at the `struct`?

Comment: You don't need a variable, something like `if (stat(myPath, &myStruct) == 0) { ... }` is good enough

Comment: @jphollowed you cannot do that way. If the function works then you can obviously check the content of the function to make sure that it has worked but if something goes wrong ( You don't have permission or file doesn't exist) your program will crash. You won't get any chance to check the content and hence never know what crashed your program because you will have no way to trigger the `errno` if you don't check the return value. This is same for almost all the syscalls, not only `stat`. Remember error handling is the sign of good programming habit.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the very simple example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
        char *fd= "test.txt";
        int y;
        struct stat buf;
        y = stat(fd,&buf);
        if(y == 0) {
        int size = buf.st_size;
        printf("%d",size); }

}
```

> On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is
>   set appropriately.

Here `stat` return value to y .Possible value of `y` is 0, -1 or any errno. I hope you'll get this.

Comment: you mean to say `struct stat buf[50]` instead of dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , Updated answer

Comment: Instead of writing some code you should explain the OP the necessity of these return types and how they are used along with `errno` to handle any exception during the syscall